# Parsing JSON array of objects in android

Tags: java, android, json, api

I want to get the lineId, destinationName and timeToStation from this api call https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/25,86,w19/Arrivals?stopPointId=490009219W&app_id=&app_key=
Can someone help with example please?
`[
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "-480785385",
    "operationType": 1,
    "vehicleId": "BJ11DSX",
    "naptanId": "490009219W",
    "stationName": "Little Ilford Lane",
    "lineId": "25",
    "lineName": "25",
    "platformName": "B",
    "direction": "inbound",
    "bearing": "245",
    "destinationNaptanId": "",
    "destinationName": "Oxford Circus",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-17T16:56:56.463Z",
    "timeToStation": 1534,
    "currentLocation": "",
    "towards": "East Ham or Manor Park",
    "expectedArrival": "2016-04-17T17:22:31Z",
    "timeToLive": "2016-04-17T17:23:01Z",
    "modeName": "bus"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "1992301652",
    "operationType": 1,
    "vehicleId": "BJ11DVA",
    "naptanId": "490009219W",
    "stationName": "Little Ilford Lane",
    "lineId": "25",
    "lineName": "25",
    "platformName": "B",
    "direction": "inbound",
    "bearing": "245",
    "destinationNaptanId": "",
    "destinationName": "Oxford Circus",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-17T16:56:56.463Z",
    "timeToStation": 1159,
    "currentLocation": "",
    "towards": "East Ham or Manor Park",
    "expectedArrival": "2016-04-17T17:16:16Z",
    "timeToLive": "2016-04-17T17:16:46Z",
    "modeName": "bus"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Prediction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "733078946",
    "operationType": 1,
    "vehicleId": "BJ11DVG",
    "naptanId": "490009219W",
    "stationName": "Little Ilford Lane",
    "lineId": "25",
    "lineName": "25",
    "platformName": "B",
    "direction": "inbound",
    "bearing": "245",
    "destinationNaptanId": "",
    "destinationName": "Oxford Circus",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-17T16:56:56.463Z",
    "timeToStation": 790,
    "currentLocation": "",
    "towards": "East Ham or Manor Park",
    "expectedArrival": "2016-04-17T17:10:07Z",
    "timeToLive": "2016-04-17T17:10:37Z",
    "modeName": "bus"
  }
]`

My AsyncTask is given belw

```
   @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args){
       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        Log.i("URL", url);
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        if(json == null) {
            Log.i("Json obj =" , "NULL");
        }
        else{
            return json;
        }
        return new JSONObject();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //String shopName ="";
       // String distance="";

        try{
            //Fetching JSON Array
            Log.i("JSON", json.toString());

            jsonData = new JSONArray(json);

            Double arrivalTime= 0.0;

            for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    busNoArray.add(json.getString(TAG_LINEID));
                    destinationArray.add(json.getString(TAG_DESTINATION));

                    arrivalTime = json.getDouble(TAG_TIME) / 60;
                    arrivalTimeArray.add(arrivalTime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            adapter = new BusTimeAdapter(BusTimeActivity.this,busNoArray, destinationArray, arrivalTimeArray);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: Are you sure here is your json `Log.i("JSON", json.toString());` logged ? You are doing everything wrong.

Comment: That is just to make sure that it is not a null reponse. What I do not understnad is how to access the objects inside the array as my doInBackground returns an object and I am not sure how to access the values inside the array.

Comment: I've added it as an answer, I used 0 for just retrieving first object but you can loop it to retrieve others as well. And added some comments to clarify those. Hope that helps you. Feel free to ask if you got some confusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be sure you have retrieved JSON String,

Then You can easily access the properties inside them like

```
try {
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
     JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); //0 for just retrieving first object you can loop it
     String myVehicleID = obj.getString("vehicleId"); //To retrieve vehicleId
     //Similarly do it for others as well
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `JSONArray = new JSONArray(json);` says Call requires API level 19. My min API is 9 so I modiefied your code to `JSONArray = new JSONArray(json.toString());` but it give me a runtime error `E/JSON Parser: Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException:` any Idea?

Comment: Yes you need to pass String as parameter  in `new JSONArray()`. It means you are not getting valid json. Please log your `json.toString()` and paste the output.